In a PFC boost converter, would input current distortion happen during initial voltage build up- when input is higher than output?
It is said that "Boost DC voltage output must be higher than the maximum line peak voltage otherwise you will introduce distortion (harmonics)"
Shown below is the simulation output for a PFC boost having a soft start input switch:
1st plot (Vn028): Boost converter MOSFET gating pulse
2nd plot: PFC input voltage (purple) and PFC output voltage (blue)
3rd plot: Rectifier output voltage (Please note there is a series N-MOS, soft start switch, between Rectifier output and PFC input)
4th plot: Current through PFC inductor (same as series N-MOS)
If you look clearly, PFC input voltage is never greater than instantaneous PFC output voltage (Plot 2). Why does the input current distortion occur during this period (rectified AC input is greater than PFC output)?



Because current will pass the PFC without regulation though D1 when it's forward biased (rectified AC voltage is higher than PFC output voltage). For a real application, this is just a passing event and won't be part of the certification process (CE, UL, others), so you only need to handle the inrush current.
